# Angular checkbox values using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to `angularjs`.So, I have an array of some values, which I want to use it in the checkbox.So,
**HTML code**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="domain">Domain</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="multiselect">
                                <div class="selectBox" ng-click="showCheckboxes()">
                                <select>
                                    <option>Select an option</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="overSelect"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="checkboxes">
                                <label for="one">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
                                <label for="two">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
                                <label for="three">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**And my array is like -**

```
$scope.tempval = [{ name: 'ABC' }, { name: 'PQR' }, { name: 'XYZ' }, { name: 'EFG' }];
```

So, Here 
I want to show these value for the chekbox, I tried different things using ng-repeat but I was not able to do it, so can anyone help me ? thanks in advance.

**CSS is**

```
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

**Controller -**

```
var.expand = false
$scope.showCheckboxes = function(){
                    var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
                                if (!expanded) {
                                    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
                                    expanded = true;
                                } else {
                                    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
                                    expanded = false;
                                }
                };
```

I also want to get all the checked values in an array .How can I do this ?

Comment: can you create a `plnkr` for the same please?

Comment: @Rohit I have checked it but it is not working.

Comment: @ganeshk check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  var expand = false
  $scope.tempval = [{ name: 'ABC' }, { name: 'PQR' }, { name: 'XYZ' }, { name: 'EFG' }];
  $scope.showCheckboxes = function() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
    if (!expand) {
      checkboxes.style.display = "block";
      expand = true;
    } else {
      checkboxes.style.display = "none";
      expand = false;
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="selectBox" ng-click="showCheckboxes()">
        <select>
               <option>Select an option</option>
        </select>
        <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
        <label  ng-repeat="item in tempval" for="{{item.name}}">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{item.name}}" />{{item.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey,Here in this problem is that if you try to select the PQR then it is selecting the ABC.Everytime it is selecting ABC.

Comment: @ganeshk Thanks for correcting me. I updated my answer. please check now

Comment: this one is perfect for me .Great answer. Just want to ask one thing,If possible, At first when I use this and checks 2 things and after that submitted it. Then when I do the same operation for second time then it is already showing the previously selected checkbox with checks. So, How can I remove that ?

Comment: @ganeshk After submitting you can again assign blank value to the ng-model object of the checkboxes.

Comment: I tried it but was not happening that is why I asked you, can you edit it in code.

Comment: Can you please provide the fiddle or plnkr so that i can look into your code.

Comment: Code is too lengthy , so I will not be able to create a fiddle or plnkr.Sorry for this.

Comment: I tried to use checked property here but still no luck, can u tell me about the checked property ?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular one checkbox  is linked with one model. But in practice we usually want one model to store array of checked values from several checkboxes. [Checklist-model](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) solves that task without additional code in the controller. You should play with attributes of  tag:

1. set `checklist-model` instead of ng-model
2. set `checklist-value` - what should be picked as array item

Answer (score 0):

The [Documentation for select directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) might help you in populating your dropdown with Angularjs.

For getting all checked values from your html try jquery -

```
var selected = [];    //create an array to hold checked checkboxes
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {    // get all checked checkboxes from the page
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));    //append each to the array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show or hide anything use the directives ng-if, ng-show, hg-hide. 
For your example:
Remove showCheckboxes function from the controller
and edit your HTML as below

```
                        <div class="multiselect">
                            <div class="selectBox" ng-click="showCheckboxes = !showCheckboxes">
                            <select>
                                <option>Select an option</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="overSelect"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="checkboxes" ng-if="showCheckboxes">
                            <label for="one">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
                            <label for="two">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
                            <label for="three">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**ng-repeat**

if I get you right try this:

```
<label for="{{item.name}}" ng-repeat = "item in tempval">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" id="{{item.name}}" />{{item.name}}</label>
```

**result**

```
                     <div class="multiselect">
                        <div class="selectBox" ng-click="showCheckboxes = !showCheckboxes">
                        <select>
                            <option>Select an option</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="overSelect"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="checkboxes" ng-if="showCheckboxes">
                        <label for="{{item.name}}" ng-repeat = "item in tempval">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" id="{{item.name}}" />{{item.name}}</label>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  var expand = false
  $scope.tempval = [{ name: 'ABC' }, { name: 'PQR' }, { name: 'XYZ' }, { name: 'EFG' }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiselect" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
                        <div class="selectBox" >
                        <button ng-click="showCheckboxes = !showCheckboxes">show checkboxes</button>
                        <div class="overSelect"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="checkboxes" ng-if="showCheckboxes">
                        <label for="{{item.name}}" ng-repeat = "item in tempval">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" id="{{item.name}}" />{{item.name}}</label>                            
                        </div>
                        <div>{{tempval | json}}</div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: This one is not working for me, when I try to click the select your option then it is not opening.

Comment: @ganeshk To solve your problem, you should use directives, try to rewrite your solution using directives